# Center JFrame in combination with pack()

Tags: java, swing, jframe, window, pack

I'm trying to center a `JFrame` i used to `pack()`, and I got it, but I think it's not **the clean way**.
This is how I'm doing it atm:

```
JFrame window = new JFrame();

//filling
//window
//with
//stuff

window.pack();
Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
int x = (dim.width - window.getPreferredSize().width) / 2, y = (dim.height - window.getPreferredSize().height) / 2;
window.setBounds(x, y, window.getPreferredSize().width, window.getPreferredSize().height);
```

I pack it after filling it to get the final `PreferredSizes`, so I can use those values in the `setBounds` method. But I don't like rebounding it after packing it.

Any better ideas?

Comment: See [window.setLocationRelativeTo(null)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setLocationRelativeTo%28java.awt.Component%29).

Comment: i'm doing it the same way, i'm very interested in a nice solution!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To center a window in the screen you need to call `window.setLocationRelativeTo(null)` right after [pack()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack%28%29) call and before making your window visible:

```
JFrame window = new JFrame();
...

window.pack();
window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
window.setVisible(true);
```

As per [Window#setLocationRelativeTo(Component c)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setLocationRelativeTo%28java.awt.Component%29) docs:

> ```
> public void setLocationRelativeTo(Component c)
> ```
>
> Sets the location of the window relative to the specified component
>   according to the following scenarios.
>
> The target screen mentioned below is a screen to which the window
>   should be placed after the `setLocationRelativeTo` method is called.
>
> - If the component is `null`, or the `GraphicsConfiguration` associated with this 
>     component is `null`, the window is placed in the center of the
>     screen. The center point can be obtained with the
>     `GraphicsEnvironment.getCenterPoint` method.

---

#### On the other hand

Some developers might advice you to use [Window#setLocationByPlatform(boolean flag)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setLocationByPlatform%28boolean%29) instead of `setLocationRelativeTo(...)` in order to honor the default location for the native windowing system of the platform where your desktop application is running. This makes sense since your application must be designed to run in different platforms with different windowing systems and [PLAF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_look_and_feel)s.

Comment: I didn't know "null" was synonymous to "middle of the screen" ;) Thanks a lot, that's what I was looking for!